# R: error in filter else if: the condition has length > 1

Tags: r, if-statement, filter

I am having problem to run this script:

```
    u <- runif(10000,0,1)

    if (u<= 0.081) {

    finv0=log(8*u+1)
    hist(finv0)

    } else if (u> 0.081 & u<= 0.134) {

    finv1=  log(8*u+1)-2
    hist(finv1)

    } else {

    finv2=  1-log(8*u+1)
    hist(finv2)

    }
```

Error in if (u < 0.081) { : the condition has length > 1

Can you help me to fix this?

Comment: you probably want something like dplyr::case_when() or data.table::fcase(). the error is because length(u)>1 but you're using it in if statements (which require scalar conditions).

Comment: Check out `?ifelse`